# Error with module main

Tags: haskell

Hello I'm doing a program with haskell and need do something like that:

```
expo :: String -> String
expo "stuff" = " Doing something "

main = do 
  expo "stuff"
```

but  when I try to run this,  this happend:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO t0' with actual type `String'
In the expression: main
When checking the type of the function `main'
```

Some one who can explain me ? ....

Comment: main=print (expo "stuff) would be fine. While you're learning, perhaps let go of your need to have a main, and just use ghci, the interactive interpreter, where you can type in what you like and it'll do it. Typing expo "stuff" into the interpreter would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to happen to the return value of `expo "stuff"`?

Let's assume you want to print it to the console:

```
main = do
  putStrLn $ expo "Stuff"
```

All statements in a do block need to be of type `IO something` (see also `let` bindings) the last must be `IO ()`.  If this doesn't make sense to you then you have run into one of haskell's famous learning curves.  Read a few more pages in the tutorials and it will become clear with practice.  *Keep Learning!*